# Google Maps changed between 3.9 and 3.10, and tiled canvas overlay

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, html5-canvas

I was working on a solution based on

> http://www.giscloud.com/sandbox/jsapi/html5/?mid=11695

On line 15, you can see the import (multi-line for easy reading)

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
```

Which in the last week started loading v3.10 (release) instead of v3.9 (now frozen).

The problem as you can see from the page is that the canvases are now loaded in the "MapPane" layer well below the other 6 layers ([Ref: MapPanes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes)). That layer is not interactive.

Has anyone come across such an issue, or better yet, is using the very solution in the link - and has upgraded it for v3.10?

**JS Fiddle**

- [doesn't work (v3.10)](http://jsfiddle.net/gmmtJ/)
- [works (v3.9)](http://jsfiddle.net/gmmtJ/1/)

---

**More info**

In v3.9, the map panes are laid out as

```
<div .. (parent)
    <div .. z-index:100.. >   --- << changed to 150
    <div .. z-index:101.. >
    <div .. z-index:102.. >
    <div .. z-index:103.. >
    <div .. z-index:104.. >
    <div .. z-index:105.. >
    <div .. z-index:106.. >
```

The code in the solution manipulates the z-index of the first pane ("MapPane"), which goes against the API's intentions...

> el.map.getDiv().firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.style.zIndex=150

My custom solution sets it to 104 instead, as I make use of the `overlayMouseTarget` (105) and `floatPane` (106) layers which need to go above it.

In v3.10, they have been rearranged as follows (you can make out the z-indexes 100-106):

```
<div .. (parent)
    <div .. z-index:200.. >
        <div .. z-index:101.. >
    <div .. z-index:201.. >
        <div .. z-index:102.. >
        <div .. z-index:103.. >
    <div .. z-index:202.. >
        <div .. z-index:104.. >
        <div .. z-index:105.. >
        <div .. z-index:106.. >
    <div .. z-index:100.. >
         < overlay tile divs >  --<< the divs parenting the canvases in the solution
             <canvas ... >
```

I am thinking that the proper "fix" is to get the tiles moved to the `floatShadow` MapPane, but does it provide the tiling benefits that an OverlayMapType does, which seems to underpin the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Direct access to pane is not better way.
To get panes correctly, your code should like this:

```
var dummyLayer = new google.maps.OverlayView();
dummyLayer.onAdd = function() {
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  console.log(panes.mapPane);
  panes.mapPane.style.zIndex = 500;
};
dummyLayer.onRemove = function() {};
dummyLayer.draw = function() {};
dummyLayer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Won't work. It puts the mappane above all others, which also puts it above the overlayMouseTarget and floatPane.

Comment: My app is `based on` the code shown, not `the code shown in and of itself`. Yes your code fixes the particular jsfiddle, but does not address the usage of layers 105/106.

Comment: Could you show me your code? I can't fix only the code you shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I post whole code of yours.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>  
  <title>GIS Cloud HTML5 Canvas Example</title>
  <style>
    body, html {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>  
  <link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/standard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.giscloud.com/sandbox/html5c.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function initialize() {

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

      map.setZoom(4);
      map.setMapTypeId('terrain');
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(35.818521016151, -100.932382588817));

      var dummyLayer = new google.maps.OverlayView();
      dummyLayer.onAdd = function() {
        var panes = this.getPanes();
        console.log(panes.mapPane);
        panes.mapPane.style.zIndex = 500;
      };
      dummyLayer.onRemove = function() {
      };
      dummyLayer.draw = function() {
      };
      dummyLayer.setMap(map);

      var gcmap = new giscloud.Html5Map(11695, map);
      map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, gcmap);
      map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, 0);

    }

  </script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div style="text-align:center"><h2>GIS Cloud HTML5 Canvas Example</h2><p>Showing interactive HTML5 vector map overlay hosted on GIS Cloud. The original project is <a href="http://www.giscloud.com/map/11695/us-unemployment-sep-2010">here</a>. </p></div>  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 70%; height: 75%;margin:auto"></div>
  <br />
  <center>requires HTML5 compatible <a href="#" onclick="return false;" title="Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE9">browser</a> - <a href="http://www.giscloud.com/blog/realtime-map-tile-rendering-benchmark-rasters-vs-vectors/">article &amp; benchmark: rasters vs vectors</a></center>
</body>
</html>
```

​